# How to get a callback in fancyBox

Tags: javascript, fancybox

I want to get a callback in fancyBox when I use the `open` function:

```
$.fancybox.open($("#some_block"));
// or
$.fancybox.open("my text");
```

How can I get a callback after the `show` block?

Comment: you should read the docs, they're pretty detailed http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/#instructions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try to use `afterShow` handler.
http://jsfiddle.net/nt7x48yr/1/

```
$.fancybox.open($("#some_block"), {
  afterShow: function() {alert('afterShow');}   
});
// or
$.fancybox.open("my text", {
  afterShow: function() {alert('afterShow');}   
});
```

Comment: Okey and how i can use afterShow in fancybox.open?